# Uploadify returns HTTP 500 error and doesn't hit the back-end at all

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, uploadify

Here's the response `onError`:

```
{
    "type": "HTTP",
    "info": 500
}
```

The back-end PHP script works fine with regular `multipart/form-data` form. But when I use Uploadify, it returns the error above right after `onOpen` event. I checked php and apache logs, nothing is there about this error. I even tried to `echo` something in the PHP code, but that doesn't show up anywhere. I'm running it locally using MAMP on port 80. I'm using Code Igniter, and there's a controller called `process` and the function `upload_image()`, so the link is not broken either.

Here's my uploadify js code:

```
$('#browse-files').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/libraries/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/process/upload_image',
    'folder'    : '/uploads/',
    'cancelImg' : '/libraries/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'buttonImg' : '/images/upload.png',
    'auto'      : true,
    'height'    : 40,
    'width'     : 313,
    'auto'      : true,
    'simUploadLimit': '1',
    'multi'     : true,
    'method'    : 'post',
    'fileExt'   : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.gif;*.png',
    'fileDesc'  : 'Web Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG)',
    'fileDataName' : 'file',
    'onOpen'    : function(event, id){
        console.log("Starting to upload an image"); //this shows up in console
    },
    'onProgress': function(event, id, fileObj, data){
        console.log("Progress: "+data.percentage);
    },
    'onComplete': function(event, id, fileObj, resp, data){
        console.log("Upload is done.");
        console.log(resp);
   },
   'onAllComplete': function(event, data){
        console.log("All uploads are done.");
   },
   'onError'    : function(event, id, fileObj, errorObj){
        console.log( JSON.stringify(errorObj) ); //and this prints the error above
   }
});
```

Comment: Maybe, controller just rejected data w/o proper header?

Comment: @kirilloid: I have tried `return json_encode($_FILES);` without any processing, but it's still returning 500. I know 500 is the server side error, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: same error today with no result

Comment: does desired folder exists? what about rights? (`chmod 777`), did you try `uploadify` "out of the box"? Also there might be a `routing` or `.htaccess` problem. Can you load desired URL with no problem (in browser)? I bet there is problem with your route routines.

Comment: in your config file, CSRF is enabled?